# Sybase SQL - Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, variables, stored-procedures, sybase

I’m trying to create a very simple stored procedure which would do the following:

```
 EXEC sp_help N’some.table’

 SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM some.table
```

So far I have the following

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE info_qry(@tbl)

 BEGIN

      DECLARE @tbl varchar(100)

      EXEC sp_help N’@tbl’

      SELECT TOP 1000 * FROM @tbl

END
```

I can’t figure it out how to pass the @tbl variable after the N’’ part so it is taken as a variable and not as a constant. How to do that?

Any help is appreciated.

Apologies about formatting I’m on mobile.

Comment: which Sybase RDBMS product (ASE? IQ? SQLAnywhere? Advantage?) and version? I'm assuming that what you want to do is direct the output of `sp_help` into the table referenced by the variable `@tbl` ... yes?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of background information. It is Adaptive Server Enterprise / 15.7. (ASE). And Yes, as You described I want to direct the output of sp_help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dynamic SQL:

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max);

set @sql = 'sp_help ''' + @tbl + '''';

exec(@sql);
```

Comment: Thanks for you prompt answer again, however I'm still doing something wrong.

In the meantime I've switched to SQL 2016 (at home) end the following query returns error:

     GO;
     CREATE PROCEDURE infoQry(tbl nvarchar(max))
     AS
          BEGIN
  DECLARE sql nvarchar(max)

  SET sql = 'sp_help ''' + tbl + ''''
   EXEC sql
  SELECT TOP 5 * FROM tbl 
   END

     Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'PROCEDURE'.
     Must declare the scalar variable "tbl".
     Must declare the table variable "tbl".
I had to remove @ symbols due to comment rules, its added in my query.

Comment: Maybe add this extra info formatted into the question.